# I want to work with a list of coordinates [Haskell]

Tags: haskell, coordinates, hugs

So I need to work with a list of coordinates, I already made a type like this:

```
type Pont = (Float, Float)
```

And I need to return a list of Floats calculated from the points I got.
What I did so far:

```
szamol :: Pont -> Float
szamol 0.0 = 0.0
szamol (x,y) = 10^(1/2)*((x^2)+(y^2))

ossz :: [Pont] -> [Pont]
ossz [] = []
ossz (h,t) = szamol h ++ ossz t
```

it gives me this error:

```
ERROR "Hazi.hs":6 - Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : szamol
*** Type          : Pont -> Float
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : (Integral a, Fractional a)
```

Comment: BTW, Hugs has now been out of development for more than a decade... why don't you use GHC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `0.0` in:

```
szamol 0.0 = 0.0
```

makes no sense. A `Pont` `Point` is a 2-tuple of `Float`s, not a single `Float`, so you can define this as:

```
szamol :: Pont -> Float
szamol (0.0, 0.0) = 0.0
szamol (x,y) = 10^(1/2)*((x^2)+(y^2))
```

Using `10^(1/2)` will fail, since the `^` operator expects the second operand to be of a type that is a member of the `Integral` typeclass. You can use `10**(1/2)`.

Using `10**(1/2)` will give you the square root of `10` (so ≈ 3.16), and will not calculate the square root of the sum of squares.

You thus likely want to use:

```
szamol :: Pont -> Float
szamol (0.0, 0.0) = 0.0
szamol (x,y) = sqrt (x*x + y*y)
```

In your `ossz` function, you make three mistakes:

1. the return type should be `Float` here;
2. you sum up with `(+)`, not with `(++)` and
3. the data constructor for a list "cons" is `(:)`, not `(,)`:

```
ossz :: [Pont] -> Float
ossz [] = []
ossz (h : t) = szamol h + ossz t
```

Here it might be better to use a combination of [**`sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) and [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
ossz :: [Pont] -> Float
ossz = sum . map szamol
```

**EDIT**: if you want to return a list of `Float`s, then you can map:

```
ossz :: [Pont] -> [Float]
ossz = map szamol
```

or with explicit recursion:

```
ossz :: [Pont] -> [Float]
ossz [] = []
ossz (h : t) = szamol h : ossz t
```

Comment: I want to return a list of floats in the function "ossz", so I changed everything like you suggested, but it doesn'n work If I want to return a list. It looks like this now:
`ossz :: [Pont] -> [Float]
ossz [] = 0.0
ossz (h : t) = (szamol h) ++ (ossz t)`

Also, the szamul function looks like this now:
`szamol :: Pont -> Float
szamol (0.0, 0.0) = 0.0
szamol (x,y) = sqrt (x*x + y*y)`

Comment: @BeryPurda: then you use `map` without the `sum`.